# Unidentified problem with jQuery's .click() function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add an 'onclick' function to an image with jQuery and for some reason it's not sticking. My code looks like:

```
//create arrow icon/button for li
var img = $('<img></ >').attr('id',i+5)
                       .attr("src","images/16-arrow-right.png")
                       .addClass("expImg")
                       .click(function(){expand(this, 'tdb', 'years', 'danwoods')})
                       .appendTo(li);
```

and the resulting  element looks like;

```
<img id="6" src="images/16-arrow-right.png" class="expImg"/>
```

It completely leaves out the onclick function, but everything else works fine. Does anyone see a problem with my code, or does the error lie elsewhere? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't expect the click event handler you're defining to show up in an HTML rendering of the element.  You're really not "setting an `onclick`"; you're binding a function to the DOM click event, which is kind of a different thing.  For starters, you can bind several such functions and they play nicely with each other.

If it's really important to you that it render, try doing:

```
.attr('onclick', "expand(this, 'tdb', 'years', 'danwoods')")
```

and see if that works for you.